# Custom GSON deserialiser

Tags: android, gson, json-deserialization

I've got multiple API responses in this format:

```
{
   status: "OK",
   error: null,
   data: [
   ]
}
```

Where the "data" field is different (single item and list of items)... So I've written a custom deserializer:

```
public class CustomDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<ServerResponse<T>> {

private Type t;

public CustomDeserializer() {
}

public CustomDeserializer(Type t) {
    this.t = t;
}

@Override
public ServerResponse<T> deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
        throws JsonParseException {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    ServerResponse<T> serverResponse = new ServerResponse<>();
    serverResponse.setError(gson.fromJson(je.getAsJsonObject(), Error.class));
    serverResponse.setStatus(gson.fromJson(je.getAsJsonObject(), ResponseStatus.class));

    if (je.getAsJsonObject().get("data").isJsonArray()) {
        JsonArray arr = je.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("data");
        T[] a = (T[]) new Object[arr.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            a[i] = gson.fromJson(arr.get(i), t);
        }
        ((ServerResponse<List<T>>) serverResponse).setData(Arrays.asList(a));

        return serverResponse;
    } else {
        T data = gson.fromJson(je.getAsJsonObject().get("data"), t);
        serverResponse.setData(data);

        return serverResponse;
    }
}
```

}

Gson setup:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(ServerResponse.class, new CustomDeserializer<Category>(Category.class))
            .registerTypeAdapter(ServerResponse.class, new CustomDeserializer<City>(City.class))
            .registerTypeAdapter(ServerResponse.class, new CustomDeserializer<Business>(Business.class))
            .registerTypeAdapter(ServerResponse.class, new CustomDeserializer<BusinessListItem>(BusinessListItem.class))
            .create();
```

But when the response come... The deserializer deserialize it in the wrong class...

Do you have any suggestions how I can fix that problem?

Comment: Please show how do you call Gson to do the deserialization.

Comment: @Seishin i realized that answer can be simplified if you provide your object type to gson. And also here is simmilar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36614097/1032167  and as you can see from comments to the first answer, you will probably still have to use specific request type of object you want to be deserialized.

Comment: @varren, I have 4 different types of response for the data field. Two of them are lists of objects. The problem is that the deserializer don't know which type to pick and deserialize into. 

I added in the question the Gson setup.

Comment: @Seishin I think gson will just use one of your deserializers and ignore the rest. To make it work you can try to use `TypeToken`  https://i.gyazo.com/f57c3c1451fcceed8a5cb897dee1587e.png but you still will have to guide gson which object to parse with type of `ServerResponse` generic value. So parsing `ServerResponse` without type info will parse `ServerResponse<Object>`.

Comment: Looks like typical chicken/egg situation. you need to parse your entire response to actually know what the type of the response is... You need to parse it "generically" with `TypeToken` as said above, then inject the whatever `data` you have into a specific class, but yeah, you do not really want to re-parse it again, especially if `data` is large

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data structure. If you have

```
public static class ServerResponse<T>{
    private Error error;
    private ResponseStatus status;
    private List<T> data;
    // getters, setters , tostring
}
```

You can use this generic deserializer:

```
public static class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ServerResponse> {
    @Override
    public ServerResponse deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
            throws JsonParseException {
        Type t = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        JsonObject jObject = (JsonObject) je;
        ServerResponse serverResponse = new ServerResponse();

        JsonElement dataElement = jObject.get("data");
        JsonElement errorElement = jObject.get("error");
        JsonElement statusElement = jObject.get("status");

        Error error = jdc.deserialize(errorElement, Error.class);
        ResponseStatus status = jdc.deserialize(statusElement, ResponseStatus.class);

        ArrayList dataObj;
        if (dataElement.isJsonArray()) {
            JsonArray array = dataElement.getAsJsonArray();

            Type listT = ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(List.class, new Type[]{t}, null);
            dataObj  = jdc.deserialize(array, listT);
        } else {
            dataObj = new ArrayList();
            dataObj.add(jdc.deserialize(dataElement, t));
        }

        serverResponse.setError(error);
        serverResponse.setStatus(status);
        serverResponse.setData(dataObj);

        return serverResponse;
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ServerResponse.class,new CustomDeserializer()).create();
ServerResponse<String> resp = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ServerResponse<String>>() {}.getType());
```

**Edit** post update after [Deserializing JSON into a class with a generic argument using GSON or Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614097/deserializing-json-into-a-class-with-a-generic-argument-using-gson-or-jackson/36617549#36617549)