# Deserializing JSON into a class with a generic argument using GSON or Jackson

Tags: java, generics, jackson, gson

I'm getting responses from my server that look like:

```
{
  "timestamp" : 1,
  "some other data": "blah",
  "result" : {
     ...
  }
}
```

for a variety of calls.  What I want to do client side is:

```
class ServerResponse<T> {
    long timestamp;
    T result;

}
```

and then deserialize that with GSON or Jackson.  I've been unable to do so thanks to type erasure.  I've cheated that using subclasses like this:

```
class SpecificResponse extends ServerRequest<SpecificType> {}
```

but that requires a bunch of useless classes to lie around.  Anyone have a better way?

I also need to be able to handle the case of result being an array.

Comment: `TypeToken` in Gson, `TypeReference` in Jackson. The array is more difficult if you meant to wrap it in `ServerResponse`.

Comment: Some frameworks allow you to specify a class type in the client request, which reifies the type parameter and causes the request to return the concrete type.  Look for a variation of the request api that takes a Class parameter.

Comment: @Pillar I'm happy to have a 2nd class ServerArrayRequest where the variable is List<T> result if that's easier.  I don't mind two, I'd prefer to not have dozens.

Comment: Jackson has a feature called [`ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features) which would let you kind of do this, but your Java code would have to have a `List<T>`. It would then be populated with a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution to type erasure in this case is the [type token hack](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) which takes advantage of anonymous classes maintaining superclass information for use with reflection.

Jackson provides the [`TypeReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html?is-external=true) type as well as an [`ObjectMapper#readValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(byte[],%20com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference)) overload to use it.

In your example, you'd use

```
ServerResponse response = objectMapper.readValue(theJsonSource, new TypeReference<ServerResponse<SpecificType>>() {});
```

Note that this is not type-safe so you must be careful that the type you try to assign to is compatible with the generic type argument you used in the anonymous class instance creation expression.

---

As for supporting both single values and arrays in the JSON, you can change your field to be of some `Collection` type. For example,

```
List<T> results
```

Then, enable [`DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY).

> Feature that determines whether it is acceptable to coerce non-array
>   (in JSON) values to work with Java collection (arrays,
>   `java.util.Collection`) types. If enabled, collection deserializers will
>   try to handle non-array values as if they had "implicit" surrounding
>   JSON array.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working for the array case, either with a T result holding a list or a List<T> result.  In either case its giving me a list<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> for each element in the result..

Comment: @GabeSechan https://i.gyazo.com/bb3da85ba63139b9426944d1f72b78c5.png works fine for me

Comment: I think the problem for me is still erasure.  I was trying to use it in a generic class itself-  a CustomVolleyRequest<Type> where Type is the deserialization type.  So its becoming an Object again with erasure.  If I pass that in like I would a class though....  I think I can make that work.

Comment: That works.  Ok, so 1 boiler plate parameter per request call instead of 1 boiler place class per type.  I think that's a win.  Time for massive refactoring

Answer (score 0):

I support `@Pillar` solution to use `Jackson` because it is so straiforward. 2 lines of code...

Here is **Gson version** that will work the same way, but you will need custom deserializer and a little reflection to achieve this.

```
public static class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ServerResponse> {
    @Override
    public ServerResponse deserialize(JsonElement je, Type respT,
                          JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {

        Type t = (respT instanceof ParameterizedType) ?
                ((ParameterizedType) respT).getActualTypeArguments()[0] :
                Object.class;

        JsonObject jObject = (JsonObject) je;

        ServerResponse serverResponse = new ServerResponse();

        //can add validation and null value check here
        serverResponse.timestamp = jObject.get("timestamp").getAsLong();

        JsonElement dataElement = jObject.get("result");

        if (dataElement != null) {
            if (dataElement.isJsonArray()) {
                JsonArray array = dataElement.getAsJsonArray();

                // can use ((ParameterizedType) respT).getActualTypeArguments()
                // instead of new Type[]{t} 
                // if you 100% sure that you will always provide type
                Type listT = ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(List.class, new Type[]{t}, null);

                serverResponse.result  = jdc.deserialize(array, listT);
            } else if(dataElement.isJsonObject()) {
                serverResponse.result = new ArrayList();
                serverResponse.result.add(jdc.deserialize(dataElement, t));
            }
        }
        return serverResponse;
    }
}
```

Use case is very simmilar to Jackson:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
           .registerTypeAdapter(ServerResponse.class, new CustomDeserializer())
           .create();

ServerResponse<MyObject> s = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ServerResponse<MyObject>>(){}.getType())
```